# Polly inside task times out

Tags: c#, polly

I'm calling an endpoint which I want to retry if it returns 404 or fail immediatly on other exceptions.

Works fine for shorter timespans, but when I run with an exponential backoff I see "Scheduling attempt 10/11 in at [date]" but no subsequent calls are made.

I want to run this in a task because I want to dequeue it from the main thread and process it in the background. Could the problem be related to the task being disposed?

```
var settingsPage = _contentQueries.GetComponent<SettingsPage>();
var retryCount = 11;
var token = _authorizationService.GetBearerToken();

Task.Factory.StartNew(currentContext => {
    HttpContext.Current = (HttpContext) currentContext;

    var captureResult = Policy.HandleResult<HttpResponse>(r => r.Status == (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound).WaitAndRetry(retryCount, retryAttempt =>
    {
        var nextAttemptInSeconds = Math.Pow(3, retryAttempt);
        _logger.Log($"Scheduling retry attempt {retryAttempt}/{retryCount} at {DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(nextAttemptInSeconds)}", activity, Level.Debug);
        return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(nextAttemptInSeconds);
    }).ExecuteAndCapture(() =>
    {
        var result = MakeWebClientGetRequest();

        if (RemoteErrorOccurred(result))
        {
            throw new Exception(result.Response);
        }

        return result;
    });


    if (captureResult.Outcome == OutcomeType.Successful)
    {
        _logger.Log("Process successful", activity, Level.Debug);
    }
    else
    {
        if (captureResult.FinalException != null)
        {
            _logger.Log($"Failed to process: {captureResult.FinalException}", activity, Level.Debug);
        }
        else
        {
            _logger.Log($"Failed to process after {retryCount} attempts", activity, Level.Debug);
        }
    }

    _databaseFactory.Dispose();
}, HttpContext.Current);
```

```
private static bool RemoteErrorOccurred(HttpResponse result)
{
    return result.Exception != null && result.Status != (int) HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using [Hangfire's](https://www.hangfire.io/) `BackgroundJob.Enqueue` in favor of `Task.Factory.StartNew`. The app pool recycle prevents such long running tasks as in my question.

Comment: +1. Polly imposes no limit on the length of delay before retry. But if the host process dies or recycles for whatever reason, the retry is lost. Polly's core target is transient faults (retry after short pause), and Polly intentionally doesn't have any backing store to support resilience for longer delays before retry, because that isn't a good fit with Polly's core architecture which executes lambda delegates predominantly inline.  And projects like Hangfire, Quartz.Net etc already cover the space well for persisted resilient jobs. Or (in the cloud) timer-triggered jobs or lambdas/functions.

Comment: @mountaintraveller Thanks for elaborating and an excellent library